# Pandas filter dataframe by values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following structure in my data frame (mydata)

```
name                values
abc                 [{"x":"pqr","y":"lrz"}, {"x":"wer", "y":"rty"}]
bcd                 [{"x":"pqs","y":"eer"}, {"x":"pqr", "y":"dww"}]
```

It has two columns. The values column has a list of dictionaries. I want to filter the dataframe where the **first element** of the values list has "x"= "pqr" value.

Expected dataframe

```
name                values
abc                 [{"x":"pqr","y":"lrz"}, {"x":"wer", "y":"rty"}]
```

I tried

`mydata[mydata["values"][0]["x"] == "pqr"]`

but I got keyerror 0. Is there any way to do this without iterating through the dataframe. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use an apply:

```
df[df['values'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['x']=='pqr')]


    name    values
0   abc     [{'x': 'pqr', 'y': 'lrz'}, {'x': 'wer', 'y': '...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `pandas.Series.str`:

```
df[df['values'].str[0].str['x'].eq("pqr")]
```

Output:

```
  name                                             values
0  abc  [{'x': 'pqr', 'y': 'lrz'}, {'x': 'wer', 'y': '...
```